# Count groups in table but if any record in 2 group is same then consider it as one group only

Tags: mysql, select, count, self-join

I am woking on production database in my organisation. I have come across one scenario. Here is the sample data which I generated. Actual data is similar only, Just changed the field names. 
My table structure is similar to this,

```
tableAi - unsigned bigint(20) - Auto increment index
loginDetails -  varchar(200)     
loginType - tinyint(4)  (2- gmail, 3 facebook)   
studentid - unsigned bigint(20)  

tableAi | loginDetails | loginType | studentId
1 | abc@gmail.com | 2 | 333
2 | abc@facebook.com | 3 | 333
3 | xyz@facebook.com | 3 | 444
4 | xxx@gmail.com | 2 | 444
5 | test@gmail.com | 2 | 555
6 | abc@facebook.com | 3 | 555
7 | ac@facebook.com | 3 | 666
8 | ac@gmail.com | 2 | 777
9 | abc@facebook.com | 3 | 777
```

I want to count total number of students (that is very simple). But here my requirement is if loginDetail is same for 2 students then consider them as one student.

So, from above example StudentId 333, 555 and 777 have same facebook email id. So, when I count number of students, I have to consider these 2 student Ids as 1 only even though gmail account is different. So, even if one login details is same, for 2 persons, I want to treat those 2 persons as 1 person only. In production data, there is such data also that I have to consider 4-5 personIds as one person only based on their login details.

So, for above sample table, I need to generate query which returns total number of students as 3. (not 5).
Distinct student Ids will be (333,555,777) , 444 and 666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some query like tis will give you the output:

```
SELECT 
 count(*), -- only for test
 GROUP_COUNCAT(t.studentId) AS stundents,
 t.loginDetails,
 MAX(t.loginType) as loginType,
 t.studentId
FROM tableAi t
GROUP BY t.loginDetails
HAVING count(*) = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks. It will count the concatenated groups only. So, lets say, my data is        
1 | abc@gmail.com | 2 | 333
2 | abc@facebook.com | 3 | 333
3 | xyz@facebook.com | 3 | 444
4 | xxx@gmail.com | 2 | 444
5 | test@gmail.com | 2 | 555
6 | abc@facebook.com | 3 | 555                                                                            7 | tabc@gmail.com | 2 | 666
8 | tabc@facebook.com | 3 | 666                                                                then also it will return 2 only. Ideally it should return 3.

Comment: i have change my answer. please check it

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But if I just consider the above scenario, it counts group concatenation sum, But lets say there is only one row with different values. Then it doesn't cover that.

Comment: please post your desired result

Comment: Output should be 3 for above sample table. If you observe the above table, since (333,555,777 has common email abc@facebook.com) so, it should be counted as 1 student. Email Ids of 444 and 666 are not being repeated in any other student Id. So, query should return 3 (real) students. Here (333,555,777) is considered as real one student only and 444 and 666 are others. So, basically if 2 studentIds have same email, then it is one real student only. To summarise, query should return real students. Thanks

Comment: It helped me to find the correct query. So, accepting it. thanks a lot.